# Google sheets - Indext match match (I assume =))

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two values that I want to match with two other values to get a specific/unique result.

How can I solve so the value in column "U" will apprear in column "N"?

The foumla needs to match column "A & I" with "P & Q" for it to find the unique value in column "U"

Here is the link to the gdocs: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pn0bdOgzE3WC0HjapO2xO1XyvDRc__v6onJooCDb0_E/edit#gid=1283845316

Please also see attached picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell N3 I entered

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A3:A)*len(I3:I), iferror(vlookup(A3:A&I3:I, {P2:P&Q2:Q, U2:U}, 2, 0)),))
```

Change range to suit and see if that works for you?

#### Reference:

- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)